# Is 'stationary' singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

[stationary](http://www.google.co.id/imgres?imgurl=http://iris-house.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/stationary.jpg&imgrefurl=http://iris-house.org/office-admin/stationary-2/&h=957&w=1300&tbnid=5Yn4eX_j-2KYcM:&q=stationary&docid=fS4_VBmiQ6AZeM&ei=88RdVorgDsesuQTdzpa4Dg&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjKpeLzhLvJAhVHVo4KHV2nBecQMwghKAEwAQ)

Does the word 'stationary' always refers to singular form?

Comment: I think you mean **stationery**.  *Stationary* means "not moving".  *Stationery* means "writing paper and other office materials".

Comment: A good mnemonic for this:  paper ends in -er.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean the papery noun objects, **stationery** is one of those grouping words. A piece of stationery versus a box of stationery, it's like: one fish and many fish, or one sheep and many sheep.

However, when enumerating individual stationery styles, one might use **stationeries**: They had a variety of stationeries on offer.

Comment: I think it is station**e**ry (writing material), not station**a**ry (not moving).

Comment: While I agree that in general mass nouns can be pluralised to mean "kinds of X", I find "stationaries" rather unlikely. I'm not saying it doesn't occur, but it seems odd to me.